# Playing a video when clicking on an element of an image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, dom-events, poster

I want to know if it's possible to play a video when you click on an element of an image, and play another video if you click on another element of the same image ?

For instance, imagine a picture of a room :

- if I click on the area where the TV set is, the image disappears and video1 starts.
- if I click on the chair, same thing but video2 starts instead.

Is this possible using HTML5 and Javascript? If so, how am I going to do that ?

Comment: With js you can find out the mouse position relative to your image. Then secondly check if your coordinates are within that range e.g. 100<x<200 and 0<y<50 (100 wide, 50 tall). Or just overlay some divs at the position you wish and make them transparent for e.g. -> every div then has its onclick action wich let the video pop up (z-index) or links to the video

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 

I like the mouse position function idea but what happens if my videos/images are displayed on another computer with a different screen resolution than mine ? Mouse positions for the elements will be different right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

I'm assuming that you have basic understanding of HTML and JavaScript. Also this will only work on browsers that have support for HTML5 and the video element specifically.

First, add a video element to your page

```
<video id="video" width="600">
  <source type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Then let's assume you have two images, Video 1 and Video 2

```
<img src="tv.png" id="video1Btn" onclick="loadVideo1()" value="Load Video 1" />
<img src="chair.png" id="video2Btn" onclick="loadVideo2()" value="Load Video 2" />
```

Once a button is clicked the JavaScript function as in the onclick attribute will be called.

```
function loadVideo1() {
 var videoEl = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
 var sourceEl = videoEl.getElementsByTagName('source')[0];
 sourceEl.src = 'video1.mp4';
 videoEl.load();
}

function loadVideo2() {
 var videoEl = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
 var sourceEl = videoEl.getElementsByTagName('source')[0];
 sourceEl.src = 'video2.mp4';
 videoEl.load();
}
```

Comment: I can do it with different images but I was asking if it was possible using a single image. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: You can get that done using the HTML map tag, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp