# How to start a video when clicking an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a video start when clicking on an image. Is there any way I can do this using javascript/jQuery?

Comment: What kind of video? HTML5, flash, objectX....? We need to see your code.

Comment: Possible double post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626673/playing-a-video-when-clicking-on-an-element-of-an-image 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406063/how-to-play-start-youtube-video-after-clicking-on-an-image

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327907/play-pause-html5-video-javascript

Comment: Please show us what you have so far. SO is not a code writing service, and you will get a better response if you provide evidence of your own work. Please read the [ask] section in the help, and this [excellent article](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: just a html5 video ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this with HTML.

```
<video controls poster="/images/the-image-to-show.png">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

This will do the job just fine. Remember, "controls" gives you the default video controls. Play/pause/sound etc

Comment: How does this solve the actual question regarding starting a video when an image is clicked?

Comment: The poster will then function as the image you click to play the video.